# Python Subprocess.Popen does not inherit JAVA_HOME

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am trying to call mvn commands from Python, for this `subprocess` module has to be used.
The problem is, this has been working for a long time and all of a sudden does not work anymore, because the executed Maven commands complain about JAVA_HOME not being set, even though it is when i manually type `echo $JAVA_HOME` into the shell.

I have no idea why it stopped working all of a sudden.

### What i would expect

```py
command= "echo $JAVA_HOME"
proc = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', command], 
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                       stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = proc.communicate()
print(str(output))
```

prints the path to my Java JDK.

```sh
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

prints the path to my Java JDK.

### What happens instead

```py
command= "echo $JAVA_HOME"
proc = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', command], 
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                       stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = proc.communicate()
print(str(output))
```

prints `b'\n'`

```sh
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

prints `epath/to/my/java/jdk`

### What i already tried

- Using `shell=True` in `Popen`: Works, but is discouraged due to security risks and it seems to use /bin/sh when executed on our Jenkins, which makes the script crash because some commands are only executable when using bash. It worked without it too, so there must be a way to get along without it.
- adding `env=os.environ.copy()` as argument to `Popen`: No effect..Even when specifying the JAVA_HOME explicitly using `env`
- Moving the JDK to a path with no weird spaces or anything like that: No effect...
- Checking the output of `os.environ['JAVA_HOME']`: Prints the path to my Java JDK

### Information

I am still using the same python version. I did not update anything that could have caused this weird behavior all of a sudden, at least i wouldnt know what it is.

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise, x64 based
I am using GIT Bash
I am using Python 3.8.5

## Update 1:

After reading something about problems of shared environment variables between WSL and Windows, i discovered that i can specify shared variables by setting a environment variable 'WSLENV'. I added `JAVA_HOME/p` to it and now Python `subprocess` no longer prints `b'\n'`, but `b'/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Users/user/Desktop/jdk11\n'`. So the problem seems to be WSL (?).

Unfortunately, Maven still says `JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE`, so this path seems not to work.

## Update 2:

By changing the `WSLENV` variable's content from `JAVA_HOME/p` to `JAVA_HOME/u`, the `subprocess` now prints the correct path to the JDK. Still, Maven fails with the same error message..

## Update 3:

For making it work with WSL enabled, check out my answer below

Comment: Are you using _cygwin_ bash or _WSL_ bash ? If _WSL_, which distrib ?

Comment: @Zilog80 Errr, i am not sure how to answer that. The Python script is executed in GIT Bash. But as i am using Docker WSL Backend, i am having 'WIndows Subsystem for Linux' installed. Echo $SHELL yields `usr/bin/bash`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You can check with `os.environ['JAVA_HOME']` to confirm that `JAVA_HOME` is defined in your Python script's environment. I suspect that it is not, so that's the issue you need to address.

Comment: @chepner Sorry, i forgot to mention that in my post, `os.environ['JAVA_HOME']` does also print the path to my JDK without any problem. I will add this to the post. I tried echo'ing $PATH with subprocess and this actually works. This points me to some WSL problems according to a blog post i am currently reading...

Comment: To be sure, can you give us the output of `bash --version` in git-bash ? (should be a 4.x) I guess you'll have to force a _'windows style'_ path for your `JAVA_HOME`, not an UNIX one. As your JDK is probably a Windows JDK.

Comment: This gives `GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys`. BTW: I updated my post, by adding environment variable 'WSLENV' the subprocess now prints something on `JAVA_HOME`, but its a weird docker-ish path. Also, maven seems not to accept it. So maybe the problem really is anything from WSL

Comment: Use `JAVA_HOME/w` with `WSLENV` to keep it _'Windows style path'_.

Comment: Its weird, but with `JAVA_HOME/w` `subprocess` fails to print the `JAVA_HOME` variable (simply prints `b'\n' again`), with `JAVA_HOME/u` it works. But when using a mvn command, maven is still complaining about `JAVA_HOME` for some reason..

Comment: Check also if you have a JRE somewhere in your `%PATH%`, make sure it is after the JDK in the order of paths.

Comment: @Zilog80 Negative, i only have one JDK installed (Adopt OpenJDK 11), no JRE or anything. Also, the path from `JAVA_HOME` is without `bin`, just as it should be. Weird..

Comment: Check the health of the JDK in `subprocess`, with a `echo "public class myTest { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.print(\"hi there.\"); } }" > myTest.java; javac myTest.java; java myTest`.

Comment: `echo $JAVA_HOME && <your_suggested_code>` gives: output: `C:/Users/mneumayer/Desktop/jdk11`  and err: `b'/bin/bash: javac: command not found\n/bin/bash: java: command not found\n'`. Weird, how is that? These commands work when i enter them in shell manually.

Comment: Just an idea, can you give us the output of `echo $BASH_VERSION  ${PATH//*[jJ][dD][kK]/jdk}` in `subprocess` ?

Comment: Yes, this returns `b'4.4.19(1)-release jdk11/bin:/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Users/mneumayer/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Scripts:/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Users/mneumayer/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38:/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Users/mneumayer/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Users/mneumayer/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Program Files (x86)/Diffuse:/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.2/bin:`

Comment: Continuing: `/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2021.1.1/bin:/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.2/bin:/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/core_perl\n'`

Comment: The `4.4.19`tells us the `subprocess` isn't running the **same** `bash` executable. The PATH output shows us that the jdk path is here defined.  What is the output of `which javac` in the  `subprocess` ?

Comment: The output actually is simply `b''`. I fixed it by disabling `Windows Subsystem for Linux` and enabling `Hyper-V` again, so indeed WSL is breaking this completely. Not sure why. Maybe i am lucky and someone will comment why it does that. If i find it out myself im gonna post. If you have any more ideas what i could try I'd appreciate to give it a shot, otherwise much thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make it work with WSL enabled, it is kinda ugly but it seems to work.

```py
command = "mvn --version"
proc = subprocess.Popen(['wsl', 'bash.exe', '-c', command],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = proc.communicate()
print(str(output))
print(str(err))
```

By appending `wsl` and `bash.exe` i managed to make it work, the output is the basic output from `mvn --version` just like expected. Notice the `.exe` which seems to tell WSL to use the same bash executable like in normal usage without `subprocess`.
Without the `.exe`, WSL seems to use a different bash executable, where `JAVA_HOME` is not defined or at least maven complains about it with the error message that i already mentioned above.

Notice that this code probably won't work when WSL is not enabled, so you would need to programmatically test if WSL is enabled and then modify the command accordingly.

Im still searching for any solution where i dont need to modify the process args, i am gonna update if i will find one.

Comment: It is like as if the Python interpreter was running under _WSL_.  How do you launch  it ? For reference, the _.exe_ effect is expected in this case : `C:>where bash` ==> `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`, `C:\>wsl which bash` ==> `/bin/bash`, `C:\>wsl which bash.exe` ==> `/mnt/c/Windows/system32/bash.exe`. _WSL_ can access the windows volume, their paths and executables.

Comment: Exactly... i am just executing the python script in GIT Bash, like `py script.py`. `where python` also says `C:\Users\mneumayer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe`
`C:\Users\mneumayer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`. Since installing WSL, Python seems to automatically decide to run in WSL mode or something like that.. What i still don't know is if this is a general problem or just a local problem.

Comment: Does `py -I -V -V` (yes, -V twice) give the same output under git-bash and under windows cmd ?

Comment: Yes, both give `Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]`. What i noticed is, one of my working colleagues has both Hyper-V AND WSL enabled at the same time, while i only have WSL enabled. He doesn't experience this issue. But not sure if this has anything to say.

Comment: Can you provide the output of  `echo "" | strace py 2>&1 | grep python` in git-bash ?

Comment: Sure, this gives `--- Process 13756 loaded C:\Users\mneumayer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python38.dll at 00007ffb34200000`. BTW, i tried the same with enabling both `Hyper-V` and `WSL`, this didn't fix anything for me. Im so confused lol

Comment: At least we are now sure that it's the windows python interpreter that is launched in git-bash. Thus, the trouble starts with python.  In your windows PATH, have you any reference to a _WSL_ path ? (\\wsl$)

Comment: To exclude any PATH trouble, can you launch the subcommand for JAVA_HOME as `subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', command]` with  `PATH=/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows py script.py`  ?

Comment: No, i don't think so actually. Also, i installed Python before WSL. I tried with your command, but still no luck - output is `b'\n`. I don't understand how its the windows python interpreter that is used together with a seemingly a WSL-owned bash executable.

Comment: I have an idea, from git-bash, under py, can you check your homedir with `import os`, `os.system("bash")` ? The same then with `os.system("bash.exe ")`  ? (if it is something like /mnt/c/... then Python launch the _WSL_ bash...)

Comment: Somehow both put me to `/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Users/mneumayer`.

Comment: I guess it's that: Try to launch the subcommand for JAVA_HOME as `subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', command]` with `PATH=/c/Program\ Files/Git/bin:$PATH py script.py` in git-bash (check where is your git bash if you've installed it elsewhere or if it requires docker path).  I guess it is the order of paths here, have you installed git-bash after _WSL_ and python ?

Comment: No Luck unfortunately, it prints `b'\n'`. I think i installed GIT after Python, but im pretty sure WSL was the last thing i installed.

Comment: Can you give us the output for `echo $BASH_VERSINFO` and `which javac` with `PATH=/c/Program\ Files/Git/bin:$PATH py`, `import os`, `os.system("bash")` in git-bash ? -from your PATH in comment, it should be `/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Program\ Files/Git/bin` or `/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin`)

Comment: Unfortunately, in GIT-Bash using `os.system("bash")` just closes the process without output. With windows cmd, when i use `PATH=/c/Program\ Files/Git/bin:$PATH py`  the python command line interpretor doesn't even open, also it says command `py` cannot be found. BTW I think its not a GIT issue, when i open normal windows cmd and type `bash --version` it also gives the other executable that we have seen when using this command in `subprocess`. Should i try it with `subprocess` instead of `os.system`?

Comment: With git-bash, does `os.system("bash")` close the process also with `PATH=/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Program\ Files/Git/bin:$PATH py` ?  With windows cmd, you should not use UNIX style PATH, try instead `PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%PATH%` then `py` then `import os` then `os.system("bash")`  (**do not be in c:\windows\system32 as working directory**).

Comment: Question 1: Yes  |  Question 2: With Windows CMD and the PATH part, `os.system("bash")` opens the git bash in the same terminal, with `bash --version` being the ordinary one (`v4.4.23(1)-release`

Comment: So for question 2, python launch then the git-bash bash (that is the goal), so the probable cause is path order. For question 1, in git-bash, if you launch `/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Program\ Files/Git/bin/bash`, does it close ? The same for `/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/bash` ?